# How to add multiple rows or columns after the body

Tags: flutter

I'm still trying to understand how to structure widgets. I have placed a container in the body already so how can I now add another row. I've removed some code to simplify my situation but hopefully this gives an idea of how my project is structured at the moment.

```
class AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, 
        //Stats Button
        child: Row(
      ), //container 

      //How can I enter a new row here    <------- WHERE I WANT TO ENTER A ROW 

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, you cannot. You can take advantage of the `children` property of a Column, the most common layout widget in all of Flutter. Flutter works on a system of nested widgets, you cannot have many parents as it all starts with one widget.

```
class AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, 
        //Stats Button
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                // nested widgets
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Judging by your class name, you just want a button. Not every widget starts with a Scaffold, that's only if you want an entire layout with an app bar or a bottom navigation bar. For simple widgets like a button, you can get rid of Scaffold entirely and just use MaterialButton like this.

```
class AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {}, //empty function
    );
  }
}
```

**More reading:**

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

https://pusher.com/tutorials/flutter-building-layouts

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

Comment: Thanks for the help I'm trying to create a to do list where you press a button at the bottom of the screen, take input and have it displayed in a list view. I'm thinking I'll start from scratch and have one main column followed by children rows for the list view and the button. Do you think that would be a good approach.

Comment: Sounds great, ListViews also have a `children` property and you can nest many columns and rows together. For the button at the bottom of the screen, I would use a Scaffold and use a `FloatingActionButton` which I recommend you do more reading on. There's an extended version of it too which can hold text.